# How Do I Run Android Studio Code from an exFAT Device?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0, exfat

I wanted to save my code from my exFAT Samsung T5 SSD. I don't have a personal laptop, so I am currently using our office laptop. I want to secure my code, but I can't seem to `build` the code saved from the SSD, but I am getting the following error:

`com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Project\Android\app\build\intermediates\navigation_json\debug\navigation.json (The system cannot find the path specified)`